# hide html attribute in inspection browsers

Tags: javascript

i want to create a video learning site.

I want people can't get to download my videos.

how to hide element attribute in inspection browsers because people can't get the video URL in inspection browsers

how to disable download button in video element

Comment: There are some libraries that use streams and blobs instead of normal video files, which can make it considerably harder for someone to download the file. One example is [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com)

Comment: @nickzoum suggested way is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'd note that **nothing** will fully protect you against this. Netflix movies get ripped the same day as their release, and Netflix has billions to spend on protection if they want. Streaming approaches make it more *difficult*, but anyone with determination and an ability to follow steps will manage to steal your videos.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide a HTML element from the browser. You could create a seperate website which host the video's but doesn't show the real link to the video (proxy website) and only allow the ip-address of the "front-end" website to access those videos.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not possible. It will be visible in the HTML source code anyways. Only server-side code won't appear in the page's source on client-side.

Sidenote: Even if you could hide the `video` tag or the video's URL in the source, the browser should download the video itself which can be found in Chrome (or other browser's) Developer Console.